# How to compare two Git working trees OR two Git diffs?

Tags: git

#### Problem definition

I want to synchronise two folders that can be both modified. If only one of them changes, it is quite simple to deal with, but when both of contains some changes, I need to check if the same file changed in both locations, I need to keep one and append a string to the filename of the other.

I know that Git is not a backup manager nor does it support any synchronisation in this sense, however, I think Git is a quite good at creation diffs between two versions of folders/files.

#### What I tried

I want to use a local repository (no remotes) with a single branch (`main`) and a worktree (which creates another branch, let’s call it `aux`).

When changes occur in both folders, I can the changes between `HEAD` (both branches point to the same commit), but I have no idea if I can either (1) compare the two diffs for comman changed files; or (2) compare the two work trees.

Prior to getting the diffs, I always stage all changes in order to prevent any subsequent changes to get in the way and also because I prefer the output format of `git diff HEAD --name-status --diff-filter=tu --find-copies-harder` (`--diff-filter=tu` is used just in case, it should not be necessary, at least not in my use case).

Of course, I can manually compare the diffs, but it seems to be much labourous:

1. get the diffs;
2. get all changed files (for renamed files both original and new filenames);
3. compare the two lists of files.

I hope there is a better way.

#### TL;DR

Is there a way to either compare two Git working trees (actually staged files in current working tree and in working tree of a worktree)?

If it is not possible, how can I compare two Git diffs (patches if you wish) for common changed files?

The solution needs to use either Git commands or something I can use in Linux terminal (BASH, Perl, …).

#### Updates

##### Update 1

Note that I don’t care about *what changed in files*, but about *what files changed and how (added, removed, modified, renamed, copied)*.

##### Update 2

Partially OT to the question (but not to the my use case describe in the *Problem definition*): is it possible to merge two working trees (or at least two commits) while automatically renaming files in conflicts? For example, if in both trees the same file is modified (no matter if it can be merged or not), `git merge` would keep one of them without additional changes and the other would be renamed (e.g. to `${orig_filename}_dupe.${orig_file_ext}` or `${orig_filename}_dupe_${number}.${orig_file_ext}`)? That would solve my problem altogether.

Comment: Look into *interdiff* and `git range-diff`. These are very different things but both may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, @torek, for trying to help me. `range-diff` operates with _committed_ code, while I’d like to commit the changes after I (manually) merge them (manually, because of custom rules I need to apply), therefore I need to get the diff between two _working trees_ (one of the usual working tree, the other of a worktree). As for GNU `interdiff`, it is a nice piece of software, but it operates on ‘full’ diffs (meaning they contain what changed in individual files), while I don’t care about _what changed in files_, however, I care about _what files changed and how (added, removed, …)_.

Comment: @torek, partially OT to the question (but not to the my use case describe in the OP): Is it possible to merge two working trees (or at least two commits) while automatically renaming files in conflicts? For example, if in both trees the same file is modified (no matter if it can be merged or not), `git merge` would keep one of them without additional changes and the other would be renamed (e.g. to `${orig_filename}_dupe.${orig_file_ext}` or `${orig_filename}_dupe_${number}.${orig_file_ext}`)? That would solve my problem altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I know neither was a direct answer. As for merging working trees directly: no, Git in general operates on *commits*, so you have to make commits from the working trees. There's almost no cost to commits: make temporary branch names and make a bunch of temporary commits *on* those branches, for instance, and then you can get the kind of thing you want. It's not going to be a simple single command though.